# Map overlays missing until screen rotation

Tags: android, android-mapview, overlays

Here I can get, and display the users current location on the map, I can retrieve and parse the Google Places json data into arrays. The problem is that although the current location overlay is displayed, the additional overlays will not appear until after I rotate the screen from portrait to landscape. It continues to work fine even if I rotate it back to portrait.

```
    // call to retrieve and parse json data
    Intent i = new Intent(this,HttpExample.class);    
    startActivity(i);  

    List<Overlay> mapOverlays;
    mapOverlays = mapView.getOverlays();
    mapView.getOverlays().clear();

    // display current location overlay
    GeoPoint point = new GeoPoint((int)(lat * 1E6), (int)(lon *1E6));   
    controller.animateTo(point);
    Drawable drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_red);
    itemizedOverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(drawable,this);

    OverlayItem overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point, "", "");

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);

    // Go through loaded arrays to display additional overlays
    drawable = this.getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.mark_blue);
    itemizedOverlay = new MapItemizedOverlay(drawable, this);

    for(int r=0; r<10; r++)
        {
            GeoPoint point2 = new GeoPoint((int)(lat_coordinates[r]*1E6), (int)(lng_coordinates[r]*1E6));
            overlayItem = new OverlayItem(point2, "", "");
            itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
            mapView.invalidate(); 
        }

    itemizedOverlay.addOverlay(overlayItem);
    mapOverlays.add(itemizedOverlay);
    mapView.invalidate();    
  }


// When the activity starts up, request updates 
@Override
protected void onResume() {
    super.onResume();
   locManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 10,
            1000*60*1, this);
}
```

Comment: Where HttpExample class stores JSON data? Maybe you don't have data on first call to onCreate and when you rotate screen onCreate get called again when data is already parsed so you get results. Give us more details...

Answer (score 0):

I added overlays in AsyncTask and did

```
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(Void result) {
        mapView.invalidate();
    }
```

To show overlays after done.
The ides is: make sure to call invalidate() on your MapView in UI thread after all overlays had been added.